# Angular array not updating view

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, socket.io, chat

I am implementing a chat module using angularJs, socketIo. (and nodeJS for backend).

In angular there is array attached to scope: $scope.messages.
For a chat client all messages are pushed into this array, and this array is rendered in the view using ng-repeat.

```
<div class="chat-window">
    <div class="chat-message" ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">{{message}}        </div>
</div>
```

However, when i push elements into 'messages' array, it is not getting rendered, unless there is a keypress or mouse event. I have checked and there no keypress or mouse event listeners. The view is somehow now getting updating automatically.

Can someone suggest me the problem?

Comment: can you post your controller's code ?

Comment: Try by running `$scope.$apply()` after elements are pushed into the `$scope.messages` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have push your data using ajax.

jQuery ajax is out of capability of angular, you need to wrap like below, it will tell the $scope.message is going to update and update the view also..

after you push the data try applying...

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.message= data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code work for me, Whenever you get new message from socket you just need to bind your (UI updations related) code inside $scope.$apply() function

```
 socket.on = function (e) {

            $scope.$apply(function () {

                //user code to update UI

            });

        };
```